# UIButton slides up when navigation bar hides

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, hide, uinavigationbar

Got a weird issue going on

NavigationViewController with 2 custom UIButtons (using storyboard). They're both horizontally-aligned at the bottom of the screen.

When I run (sim or real), everything looks/behaves fine.

I had a need to hide the top navigation bar via:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Now when I run, at the same time the nav bar slides up out of view, one of my two buttons slides up as well!

Deleted the buttons and recreated, but still the same behavior.

Also checked in the Document Outline panel in storyboard in case some funky layering issue, but both buttons are listed sequentially inside the View.

Anyone help, please?
Thanks
Tony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your autosizing masks of 2 buttons in storyboard if you don't use autolayout or your constraints if you are using autolayout.

Comment: Dthien - thanks for the suggestion. Somehow, auto layout got switched off in storyboard. Switched it back on, tweaked a few things and we're cooking again.